# SkMaps not using scout audio

Tags: android, navigation, media, skmaps

I am using scout audio advice in skmaps, it is not detecting the audio and no advice is provided.

```
final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = new SKAdvisorSettings();
    advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_EN);
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(mapResourcesDirPath + "Advisor");
    advisorSettings.setResourcePath(mapResourcesDirPath + "Advisor/Languages");
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("en");
    switch (currentMapAdvices) {
        case AUDIO_FILES:
            advisorSettings.setAdvisorType(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorType.AUDIO_FILES);
            break;

    }
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().setAudioAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Android demo project, the audio files are not included by default: the config files are there, but the actual audio files were not included (the reason being their size) - you'll have to modify the SKMaps.zip archive and include all the sounds file from [here](http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7250-iOS-amp-Android-Language-files-for-2-5-0-and-2-5-1)

Let me know if this fixes the issue